tqdm_notebook.get_lock().locks = []
I came accross this code, can anybody tell what it does?
I was going through a jupyter notebook on kaggle when I came accross this code in import cell.

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm as tqdm_notebook

tqdm_notebook.get_lock().locks = []



tqdm is a python library that instantly make your loops in the code show a smart progress meter.
The first line of the code imports the tqdm function from the tqdm.notebook module and aliases it as tqdm_notebook.
The second line, however, modifies the internal locking mechanism of tqdm. tqdm_notebook.get_lock() returns a multiprocessing.Lock object that is used by tqdm to handle progress bars in a thread-safe manner, especially in parallel computing environments.
